# SQL/Sybase database not returning results

Tags: sql

I am passing a variable to the database that contains a list of companies... the var is passing but the database is not returning a result. How do I pass the list? and what kind of Where statement would I use?

Comment: I'm not really sure how you pass the list, but if you do it by passing  the object "list", I'm not sure that will work, have you tried concatenating all company names (assuming that's what you pass) in a string value and using that var?

Comment: My list is IBM,WalMart,KMart, and when the user selects the ALL from the dropdown list the list is passed. Problem I have is that first I am not good a SQL and second the list is a comma deliminated list but I don't know how to get the db to use multiple VARCHARs and return results.

Answer (score 2):

If we are passing a comma seperated list to a stored procedure to retrieve a number of records that have one of these strings as a value in a field we use a SQL function. This function returns a table wich can be used to filter the data.

This is our function (you should execute the create before using it)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableFromString]
(
    @string NVARCHAR(4000),
    @separator CHAR
)
RETURNS @resultTable TABLE (string NVARCHAR(255))
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(255)
    IF (LEN(@string) > 0)
      BEGIN
        DECLARE @start INT,
                @charIndex INT
        SET     @start = 1
        SET     @charIndex = CHARINDEX(@separator, @string, @start) -- Get the position of the first seperator

        WHILE ( @charIndex >= 0 )
          BEGIN
            IF @charIndex = 0 -- No seperator found, take the whole string and insert it in the result table
              BEGIN
                SELECT  @myString = SUBSTRING(@string, @start, LEN(@string) - @start + 1)
                SET     @charIndex = -1
              END
            ELSE
              BEGIN
                SELECT  @myString = SUBSTRING(@string, @start, CHARINDEX(@separator, @string, @start) - @start)
                SET     @start = CHARINDEX(@separator, @string, @start) + 1 -- Set the start position of the char after the seperator
                SET     @charIndex = CHARINDEX(@separator, @string, @start) -- Get the position of the next seperator
              END

            INSERT INTO @ResultTable (string) VALUES (@myString)
          END
      END

    RETURN 
  END
```

This is how the function then can be used:

```
SELECT  YourField1, 
        YourField2, 
        ... 
FROM    YourTableName 
WHERE   YourFieldx In ( SELECT  string 
                        FROM    dbo.GetTableFromString('IBM,WalMart,KMart', ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post what you're doing.

It sounds almost as if you had a VARCHAR variable containing a comma separated list to a stored procedure, in which case the SP would need to use dynamic sql, but I can't tell.